# How many pairs?

Tags: code-golf

<sup>*Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806914/how-many-pairs-are-in-this-array-of-strings)*</sup>

Your challenge is very simple: take input in the form of `lookupString string1 string2 ... stringN` and output how many pairs of strings there are.

But there's a catch! There are two ways of interpreting "pairs." The first way is combinations. For example,

```
       1      2     3      4
orange orange apple orange orange
```

(the first `orange` is the lookup string) has 3 pairs of oranges, since there is #1 and #3, #3 and #4, and #1 and #4.

The second way of interpreting it is adjacent pairs. For example, the same input would have a result of 1 with this interpretation, since there's only one pair in which both oranges are next to each other. (#3 and #4)

You must write two programs, one with the first interpretation and another with the second. Your score is the sum of the length of the two programs. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest score wins.

Comment: "Your score is the length of the two programs *combined*". combined in which way? Sum of the lengths? L_1 ^ L_2? L_1 * L_2? max(L_1, L_2)?

Comment: This question could probably be a lot clearer with rewording to avoid the word "pair". I see six pairs according to the first metric and two pairs according to the second metric.

Comment: @Peter The first `pear` is the search string. Also, it's intentionally confusing :P Why did you think I chose "pear" as my example? :D

Comment: [All questions on this site should have a clear specification of what constitutes a correct submission.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As things stand you're asking people to read your mind.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Meh, okay then, edited

Comment: The problem wasn't the use of `pear` but the lack of explanation of what the lookup string was about, and in particular that it wasn't participating directly in the pairs counted. The numbering makes that much clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## J, 24 characters

#### Anywhere - <del>14</del> 11

```
2!+/}.{.=;:
```

is 2 choose (`2!`) sum (`+/`) of the beheading (`}.`) of the first row (head) (`{.`) of the self-classification (`=`) of the words (`;:`) of its argument

beheading means "drop the first element and return the rest".

#### Adjanced - 13

```
+/2*/\}.{.=;:
```

is the sum (`+/`) of products (ANDs) within each two-element prefix (`2*/\`) of the beheading (`}.`) of the head (`{.`) of the self-classification (`=`) of the words (`;:`) of its argument

ex:

```
   s=.'pear pear apple pear pear'
   +/#\2}.#~{.=;:s
3
   +/2*/\}.{.=;:s
1
```

Comment: For the first program, the obvious solution (IMO) is shorter `2!+/}.{.=;:` at 11 chars

Comment: @Volatility thanks - I knew I was something missing but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 48 + 59 = 107

### Anywhere – 48

```
s,*L=input().split()
c=L.count(s)
print(c*~-c/2)
```

### Adjacent – 59

```
s,*L=input().split()
print(list(zip(L,L[1:])).count((s,s)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 38 + 45 = 83

#### Anywhere: 38

- -2 chars: Two statements was shorter than one.

```
l,*a=gets.split
p (n=a.count(l))*~-n/2
```

#### Adjacent: 45

- -2 chars: Borrowed `x==[l,l]` from Doorknob.
- -2 chars: `find_all` => `select`
- -12 chars: `select` => `count`

```
l,*a=gets.split
p a.each_cons(2).count([l,l])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica <s>33+42 = 75</s>  31+40 = 71

**Program 1**

```
Binomial[Count[Rest@#, #〚1〛, 2] &
```

Example

```
Binomial[Count[Rest@#, #〚1〛, 2] &[{"orange", "orange", "apple", "orange", "orange"}]
```

> 3

---

**Program 2**

```
Count[Partition[Rest@d, 2, 1], {e = #〚1〛, e}] &
```

Example

```
Count[Partition[Rest@d,2,1],{e=#〚1〛,e}] &[{"orange","orange","apple","orange", "orange"}]
```

> 1

Comment: You can replace "[[1]]" by "〚1〛".:)

Comment: Thanks. It took me a bit to figure out just how to do that. (Paste double brackets first as regular text then copy and paste into the code.)

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 46 + 58 = 104

Posting my own solution first as I always do:

**Anywhere - <s>49</s> 46**

```
l,*a=gets.split;p ((1..a.count(l)).inject:*)/2
```

**Adjacent - <s>65</s> 58**

```
l,*a=gets.split;c=0;a.each_cons(2){|x|c+=1if x==[l,l]};p c
```

`l,*a` stolen from daniero :P

Comment: Sure your first program is correct? Your own example input gives you 6, while you state the answer is 3.

Comment: @daniero Whoops, right. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

## R : 82

#### Anywhere: 38 characters

```
a=scan(,"")
choose(sum(a[-1]==a[1]),2)
```

`sum(a[-1]==a[1])` returns the number of corresponding item and `choose` computes the corresponding binomial coefficient.

#### Adjacent: 44 characters

```
a=scan(,"")
sum(diff(which(a[-1]==a[1]))==1)
```

`which(a[-1]==a[1])` returns the indices of the matching items, `diff` computes the difference between those indices and `sum(...==1)` returns the number of differences being 1 (i. e. the number of pairs of adjacent matching items).

Answer (score 0):

## K, 20 + 44 = 64

#### Anywhere: 20

```
{-1++/a~\:*a:" "\:x}
```

#### Adjacent: 44

```
{+/min'(*h)~/:/:(2*!-_-(#a)%2)_a:1_h:" "\:x}
```

.

```
k){-1++/a~\:*a:" "\:x}"orange orange apple orange orange"
3
k){+/min'(*h)~/:/:(2*!-_-(#a)%2)_a:1_h:" "\:x}"orange orange apple orange orange"
1
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - 166 chars

```
F=function(A){return A.match(RegExp(A.split(' ')[0], 'g')).length-1}

G=function(A){C=0;R=A.split(' ').splice(1);for(i=0;i<R.length-1;i++)R[i]==R[i+1]?C++:0;return C}
```

Edited to be separate functions.

Comment: You have to include the S/F/R declaration characters in both snippets...